# Display appears ghostly, but works on first touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have made a UIView which contains a table and some buttons. This view is called by a UIViewController which is called by a tab-bar controller. There is no IB involved.

When the view comes up it only has the outlines of the objects. e.g. the following button comes out without its label:

```
brect = CGRectMake(80, 330, 60, 27);
centern=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(brect), CGRectGetMidY(brect) );
UIButton * button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button2 setFrame:brect];
[button2 setCenter:centern];
[button2 setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(deldate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:button2];
```

As soon as I make the first touch everything appears as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

[self.view addSubview:button2];

self is an instance of UIViewController.
self contain a view. you should add you UIButton to view, not viewController.

Comment: you did not read the question. The self in the example is actually a UIView.